# 429: Too Many Requests: retry after 18053 only on telegram.sendContact

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I've got an issue with Too many requests only when I try to send a contact via telegram.sendContact. But when I am sending a message via telegram.sendMessage everything is fine.

I think I may have done some loop somewhere haven't close requests or something which are still pending or something or it's an issue with the framework.

I already tried to put `ctx.answerCb` everywhere where I 've found but it did not help.

**EDIT:**
I already tried to start a new project with only this line and I get the error anyway.
There must be some updates or something that caused that weird behaviour because before it seemed to work fine for me. I didn't notice any issues with Contacts

```
bot.hears(
    /(Contacts)|(Контакты)|(Контакти)/i,
    //@ts-ignore
    getUserInfo,
    updateUserActivity,
    async (ctx: ITelegramContext) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      ctx.telegram.sendContact(
        //@ts-ignore
        **********,
        +***********,
        "name"
      )
    }
  );
```

```
(node:8620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 429: Too Many Requests: retry after 17496
    at C:\Users\Валерий\Documents\Projects\TelegramBOT\node_modules\telegraf\core\network\client.js:281:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:8620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8620) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: I am facing this issue now! Did it resolve for you?

Comment: @CoderBC unfortunately no, I haven’t